# Add the date to the filename in log4j?

Tags: java, log4j

can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code! not able to append the datestamp to the file name

```
# Set root logger level to DEBUG .
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG,R
log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.R.File=${LOG4J_ROOT}/Employer/EmployerDocUpload.log
#log4j.appender.R.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
##log4j.appender.R.File=C:/log/AccountInfo.log
#log4j.appender.R.MaxFileSize=50000KB
## Keep one backup file
#log4j.appender.R.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.R.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern=[%p] %d %c %M - %m%n 

log4j.logger.com.carefirst.portal=DEBUG,INFO,ERROR
```

i cannot make any changes in xml!

Answer (score 1):

#### Underlying problem

The problem with [`org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/DailyRollingFileAppender.html) is that you can lose data (occurs just when the file is renamed). With this implementation, the rename of file occurs , for example, according to your date pattern, in the midnight, when the day of month changes in the system date. You can try that changing the day in your system date.

#### Solution

If you want to use a date pattern, log4j recommended to use [Apache Extras for Apache log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/extras/). <sup>**1**</sup> You need to use the classes [`org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/extras/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/rolling/RollingFileAppender.html) and [`org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/extras/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/rolling/TimeBasedRollingPolicy.html). e.g.: <sup>**2**</sup>

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, R
log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.R.rollingPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy
log4j.appender.R.rollingPolicy.fileNamePattern=logs/file%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log
log4j.appender.R.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.R.layout.conversionPattern=[%p] %d %c %M - %m%n
log4j.logger.com.carefirst.portal=WARN
```

---

*Notes*

1. In that case, you need to add the respective jar ([apache-log4j-extras-1.2.17.jar](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=log4j/apache-log4j-extras/1.2.17/apache-log4j-extras-1.2.17.jar)).
2. With that configuration, the resulting name will be `logs/file2014-08-28.log`